Differential Geometry of Curves and Surfaces from Riemannian Geometry
I'm a relativist. Hence, I have a working knowledge of Riemannian geometry, but I never really studied differential geometry of curves and surfaces. I know the traditional path is to start with curves and surfaces and then go to smooth manifolds, Riemannian geometry and etc, but I would like to know if there are any references that work backwards. Namely, I'd like a reference that defines concepts such as Gaussian and geodesic curvature using the tools from Riemannian geometry and use this language to discuss, for example, Gauss'Theorema egregium and the Gauss–Bonnet theorem (especially if they have generalizations to higher dimensions).
Are there any such references?

Good question. I have never found one. One book that uses differential forms and moving frames is O'Neil's book (https://shop.elsevier.com/books/elementary-differential-geometry-revised-2nd-edition/oneill/978-0-12-088735-4). I also like Peter Petersen's notes (https://www.math.ucla.edu/~petersen/DiffGeo.pdf). I'm hoping that someday I'll write a book using a more modern approach.

Have you looked at Lee's Introduction to Riemannian Manifolds?

That is done in these references: https://mtaylor.web.unc.edu/wp-content/uploads/sites/16915/2018/04/analmv.pdf, https://mtaylor.web.unc.edu/notes/differential-geometry-riemann-surfaces-cr-manifolds-index-theory/

If you already got a good understanding of differential geometry, I would recommend studying surfaces as Riemann surfaces. Its fun in my opinion, which is a plus.

My personal preference was Lee for the more direct presentation along the lines you’re asking, and Spivak for bedtime reading. The others are essentially treatments of surfaces using differential forms (but still very interesting reading in their own right, and of course important).


Chern, Chern, Lam, Lectures on Differential Geometry, Chapter 5. Given that the Chern-Gauss-Bonnet theorem bears his name, I think this would be one to not miss.

Dieudonne Treatise on Analysis Vol IV, chapter 20, section 13-14.  Here, he talks about curves and hypersurfaces in Riemannian manifolds. But the treatment of hypersurfaces is very short (lots of exercises though… even if long and some difficult). And then surprisingly, much later in Vol IX (available in French, not English) he gives the Gauss-Bonnet formula as a corollary (paragraph 24.46.12). As far as general to special is concerned, this is a nice book but for the specific topic of Gauss’s Theorema Egregium and Gauss-Bonnet, I wouldn’t recommend this (he essentially treats these as trivial corollaries subordiate to his main discussion and doesn’t elaborate).

Lee, Introduction to Riemannian Manifolds. He introduces curvature in chapter 7 (one of the cleanest descriptions of the algebraic properties/decomposition of curvature, and how the various pieces of scalar, Ricci, Weyl tensor transform), then chapter 8 talks about submanifolds (and the plethora of curvatures associated here) and chapter 9 is about the Gauss-Bonnet theorem. This is a wonderful treatment overall.

Loomis and Sternberg Advanced Calculus, Chapter 11 Appendix II. This is more so a short introduction to vector-valued differential forms, followed by a long problem set, covering the classical differential geometry of curves and surfaces. But I think this is still a very fun read/work-along.

Michael Taylor Partial Differential Equations II, Appendix C. This is a very rapid treatment of connections in vector bundles, second fundamental forms of subbundles, and a section for the Gauss-Bonnet theorem. So, if you want a quick discussion of everything, this is a nice appendix (besides lots of cool PDE stuff).

O’Neill Elementary Differential Geometry, chapter 6. This is more of a special to general book, so technically it’s not what you’re asking for, but it’s a very nice book. Also, for someone with background in all the abstract formalism, this book will be super down to earth (not to be mistaken for sloppy/unrigorous), and you can very quickly get through it and develop lots of intuition (I definitely did).

Spivak, A Comprehensive Introduction to Differential Geometry, Vol III. Here you have all the stuff about surfaces, surfaces in 2D, Gauss-Bonnet and lots of other fun stuff.

Sternberg Lectures on Differential Geometry, Chapter VI. I’m pretty sure Sternberg wrote this book much earlier than his book with Loomis, and in the above book, he essentially condensed this entire chapter into a little appendix in exercise form above. So, if you want a more textbook-feel, then you can consult this.


